# Should I be using Swift ContiguousArray's to hold image data?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-graphics

I am currently using a buffer of type `[UInt8]` to hold pixel data read from a CGImage as follows:

```
var pixels = [UInt8](repeatElement(0, count: bytesPerRow*Int(height)))
let context = CGContext.init(data: &pixels,
                             width: width,
                             height: height,
                             bitsPerComponent: 8,
                             bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                             space: colorSpace,
                             bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
 context!.draw(cgImage, in: rect)
```

This code makes the general assumption that `pixels` is a contiguous array of bytes holding the image data and it seems to work fine. I have this uneasy feeling I should be using [`ContiguousArray`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray)'s for this. Am I really living dangerously here and should be doing something else?

Aside: I miss plain C when I always knew what was going on. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference between `ContiguousArray` and `Array` is the latter uses a different storage when the element type is a class or `@objc` protocol (this is so it can easily bridge to Obj-C). If the element type is not a class, they both use the same storage internally and it doesn't matter which one you pick.

In your case, the element type is not a class, so `[UInt8]` will behave the same as `ContiguousArray<UInt8>`.

Comment: OK. I'll drive on then.